# How to change label/reference formats

Tags: cross-referencing

I have just been using the default label and reference formats, i.e. `$\label{eqn:a}$` and `\ref{eqn:a}` but I was wondering if there's a way to change the format of the references.  For example if I am referring back to Theorem 1.1 `$\label{thm:1.1}$` using `\ref{thm:1.1}` it shows in the `.pdf` file as simply 1.1. 
I would like my references to say more than the number, i.e. to say Theorem 1.1 in the `.pdf` (I would also like this to be true for my Definitions and Lemmas). Obviously I know that this doesn't make sense for a line in a proof but is there a way to change the format when you are referring to a labelled theorem(or definition/lemma/etc.)??

Comment: `\usepackage{cleveref}` and `\cref{eqn:a}` etc.

Comment: I have changed all my refs to clever ref but now it just gives me whats in the curly brackets, i.e. \cref{eqn:a} gives eqn:a. Is there another way or do I have to go and manually change all of my labels?

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong there. Without any document this is hard to tell!

Comment: Please show us a short, compilable code resulting in your error.

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is to use `cleveref` and its `\cref` or `\Cref` commands to include the type of the referenced counter, e.g. an equation or a theorem. The `\Cref` is used for uppercase purposes, e.g. at the beginning of a sentence.

Please note, that `\usepackage[english]{cleveref}` etc. is perhaps more useful, depending on the needed language.

`cleveref`'s output format for references can be reconfigured using `\crefformat` etc.

`cleveref` should be the last package be loaded here!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]


\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

In \cref{Einstein} and in \cref{theo} or \Cref{theo} we'll see that ...



\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{Einstein}
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem} \label{theo}
First we have...
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using autoref. I think it is included in the thmtools package (https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools).

`\autoref{theorem-label-here}` will render Theorem 1.1.

Edit: Sorry, my bad, `autoref` comes from the `hyperref` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en).

Comment: `\autoref` comes from the `hyperref` package